# How to compare two List in c# and Update values in 1st List?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, select, foreach

I have two lists and I want to compare these and update below fields using 2nd list value `StudentAddressLine1,StudentAddressLine2,StudentAddressPincode,StudentAddressCity,StudentAddressState`

Student Class

```
public class Student
    {
       
        public string StudentNumber { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string StudentClass { get; set; }
        public string StudentPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string StudentEmail { get; set; }
        public string StudentFatherPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string StudentFatherEmail { get; set; }
        public string StudentMotherPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string StudentMotherEmail { get; set; }
        public string StudentAddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string StudentAddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string StudentAddressPincode { get; set; }
        public string StudentAddressCity { get; set; }
        public string StudentAddressState { get; set; }
        
    }
```

AddressFromExternalAPI Class

```
public class AddressFromExternalAPI
    {
        public string SNumber { get; set; }
        public string SName { get; set; }
        public string SClass { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string Pincode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State  { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is my code where I use a loop and compare two lists and update the fields

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Student> getStudentDetails(IEnumerable<Student> students)
        {
            var studentList = new List<Student>();
            var addresslist = getStudentAddress(students)
            studens.ForEach((y, index ) =>
            {
                
                foreach (var address in addresslist)
                {
                    
                        studentHelper.addAddress(y, ds);
                    
                    studentList.Add(y);
                }
            });
            return studentList;
        }
            
public static void addAddress(Student student, AddressFromExternalAPI address)
        {
            student.StudentAddressLine1 = address.AddressLine1;
            student.StudentAddressLine2 = description.AddressLine2;
            student.StudentAddressPincode = description.Pincode;
            student.StudentAddressCity = description.City;
            student.StudentAddressState = description.State;
           
        }
```

could you please advise some other way to implement this logic instead of foreach?

Is there any other way instead of doing multiple loops?looking for a more compact solution?

Comment: Updating lists is not possible without loops. Do you just want a more compact solution doing the loops under the hood? (LINQ)?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg yes instead of loop .can we do this in LINQ?

Comment: LINQ is for Query, not for Update. `foreach` is right operator here.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv can we use select and where ?

Comment: If you want to improve the speed and performance of the program, you can use `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Is there anything wrong with writing it like my answer?

Comment: Your code has multiple errors - can you correct them? (E.g. `addAddress` (bad name) references a variable named `description`, `getStudentDetails` references a variable named `studens`. `AddressLine1` is duplicated in `class Student`. `RowNo` is not defined. `studentHelper` is not defined. etc.)

Comment: Your test of `rowIndex` against `address.ID` makes no sense to me: what is `ID`? Can it be duplicated? When will it be different from `rowIndex`?

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring `ID`, and assuming matching based on Number, Name and Class is sufficient, you can store the addresses in a `Dictionary` and lookup the matches:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Student> getStudentDetails(IEnumerable<Student> students) {
    var addressDict = getStudentAddress(students).ToDictionary(a => (a.SNumber, a.SName, a.SClass));
    var studentList = students.ToList();

    foreach (var student in studentList) {
        if (addressDict.TryGetValue((student.StudentNumber, student.StudentName, student.StudentClass), out var address)) {
            student.StudentAddressLine1 = address.AddressLine1;
            student.StudentAddressLine2 = address.AddressLine2;
            student.StudentAddressPincode = address.Pincode;
            student.StudentAddressCity = address.City;
            student.StudentAddressState = address.State;
        }
    }

    return studentList;
}
```

Comment: Need index to be added in final results

Comment: @itsme What does that mean? Your code doesn't add index to any final results?

Comment: i would like to add rowIndex (var rowIndex = index + 1;) in studentList

Comment: @itsme What is `index` in that expression? Why? `studentList` is a `List<Student>` - every element is accessible by index. `Student` has no field to hold a `rowIndex` - where would it go in a `List<Student>`?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to make it as much as possible with the information given. `List<T>.ForEach(Action<T>)` cannot get **index**.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Student> getStudentDetails(IEnumerable<Student> students)
{
    var addressList = getStudentAddress(students);
    var result = students
        .Select((student, index) => (student, index))
        .SelectMany(pair => addressList,
            (pair, address) => (pair, address))
        .Where(p =>
            p.pair.index + 1 == p.address.ID &&
            p.pair.student.StudentNumber == p.address.SNumber &&
            p.pair.student.StudentName == p.address.SName &&
            p.pair.student.StudentClass == p.address.SClass)
        .Select(p => (p.pair.student, p.address));

    var studentList = new List<Student>();
        
    foreach (var (student, address) in result)
    {
        addAddress(student, address);
        studentList.Add(student);
    }

    return studentList;
}
```